# Visualization / sketch for this basic proof about subspace topology

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, visualization

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $A\subset X$ a subset equipped with the induced metric $d_{A}$.
>       Then the open subsets of $(A,d_{A})$ are exactly the intersections of open subsets of of $(X,d)$ with $A$: $B \subset A$ is open in $(A,d_{A})$ iff there exists an open subset $Y \subset X$, so that $B = A \cap Y$.

My proof of "$\implies$" is pretty straight forward:

Let $B\subset A$ be an open subset.
Define
\begin{equation*}
 U_{\varepsilon}^{Z}(x)
 := \{ y \in Z: d_A(x,y) = d(x,y) < \varepsilon\}
\end{equation*}
for any subset $Z \in X$.
Because $B$ is open, for every $x \in B$ there exists an $\varepsilon_{x} > 0$ so that 
\begin{equation*}
 B\supset U^{A}_{\varepsilon_{x}}(x)
 = A\cap U^{X}_{\varepsilon_{x}}(x).
\end{equation*}
The set
\begin{equation*}
  Y := \bigcup_{x \in B}U^{X}_{\varepsilon_{x}}(x)
\end{equation*}
is open in $X$ because it's the union of open sets in $X$.
Furthermore we have $B = A\cap Y$.

**But I am having trouble visualizing this: I can't think of a way to sketch the scenario so that $U^{A}_{\varepsilon_{x}}(x) \neq U^{X}_{\varepsilon_{x}}(x)$, since when I draw $X$ to be a box and $A$ a circle inside it and $B$ a smaller circle in $B$, we alway have $U^{A}_{\varepsilon_{x}}(x) = U^{X}_{\varepsilon_{x}}(x)$.**

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw $X$ to be the plane and $A$ to be the $x$-axis.

Comment: This is in two dimensions, right?, So $B$ would be an intervall $(a,b)$ on the $x$-axis?

Comment: Sort of, but more properly speaking $B$ would be a union of open intervals on the $x$-axis, since that is the usual description of open subsets of the $x$-axis.

Comment: Sure, but when I want to draw a sketch, an interval is more convenient, right?

Comment: Sure, for purposes of a sketch that's fine, since the open intervals form a basis for the topology on $\mathbb R$.